# Callback when user denies permission to use camera on android while using react-native-camera

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-camera

I'm using `react-native-camera` to take pictures in an android app. As soon as user reaches the camera page, the **library itself** asks for permission to use the device's camera on android phones (with api level >22). (Please note that I'm **not** manually asking for camera permission by using `PermissionsAndroid` api of `react-native`).

Since asking for camera permission is inherent in this library, I'm expecting that it should by itself provide with appropriate callbacks when user grants or denies permission.
I need to call `goBack()` if user denies the camera permission but could not find any appropriate callback method in their documentation wherein `goBack()` could be called.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check permissions manually.

React native permissions can help https://github.com/yonahforst/react-native-permissions